# iOS: Touch ID prevent user from closing app when pressing too strong

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

is it possible to prevent the app from closing when my app asks for a fingerprint and the user presses the home button instead of only let the finger rest? I know and understand that it shouldn't be possible everywhere else, but it would be nice if the app wouldn't close when asking for the fingerprint.

Comment: we can't block user from closing your app, it is not possible and never will be

Comment: ok, as I said - I totally get it that it should never be allowed to prevent the user from closing the app in "normal" state, but while asking for Touch ID it would be nice as sometimes users press the home button there...

Comment: Would it be nice. Yes. Is it possible. No.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612

Comment: this is still not possible if it was a missclick, it should close app

Comment: There are apps on my iPhone that ask for touch id at launch. It would be somewhat annoying if, when I open them by accident, I couldn't close them without authenticating because they disabled closing while waiting for touch id. Nobody is going to blame you for accidentally closing your app when they were trying to touch id.

Comment: @JeremyP you do not have to authenticate, you can cancel...

Comment: I don't care. When I press the button, it is because I want the app to go away. If I accidentally press the button too hard while doing touch id, I don't blame the app writer, I blame my fat fingers - or maybe Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It is not ever possible to change regular system behaviour, even though some users might press too hard and go back home that is the behaviour that everyone expects, want to go home, press the home button and it always works

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, what you are trying to do is getting out of the scope of your application and change the behavior of the device. Apple won't allow it, ever.

They might change the behavior if they think it's better to handle it like that, you can send them a message. But they'll probably never do that as they are killing Touch ID for the sake of Face ID.